# Derivative of $f(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor \sin ^2 (\pi x) $

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

To help with the problem I first plotted the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fhw5aknliq).

Hence for $ x \in (0,1): f'(x) = 0 $

For $x \in (n,n+1), n \in \mathbb{N}$

$f(x) = n \sin^2 (\pi x) $ and thus $f'(x) = 2 \pi n x \sin (\pi x ) \cos (\pi x )$

Finally for $x \in (-n, -n+1) , \ f(x) = -n \sin^2 (\pi x) $ so that $f'(x) = -2 \pi n x \sin (\pi x ) \cos (\pi x )$

Is it correct to assume that the function is not differentiable at $x \in \mathbb{Z} $ because the left and right-hand derivatives would differ in signs and hence the function is not differentiable there.

Comment: The derivatives do not differ in sign since $\sin (\pi z) = 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @player3236 has noted, when you actually evaluate each of those derivatives in the limit at the integer $n$, even though the left and right derivatives are different functions of $n$, both of those functions take the value of $0$ at integers, since $\sin(\pi x)$ is $0$ for integer $x$. Thus, the derivatives are the same, and the derivative exists and is equal to $0$ at integers, since the left and right side limits of it match up and are equal to $0$.

Comment: So therefore at integer values, the derivative exists and equals to 0?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And that makes sense, since it flattens out directly in the graph